# Animation paused partially not working on Edge

Tags: animation, microsoft-edge

I'm currently having trouble while testing the compatibilty of my website on Edge.
Indeed, I have a CSS animation which allows a cosmonaute to move and rotate through the page. 
When the mouse is over the cosmonaute, it's supposed to stop running and display a "hello".
It works on Chrome, Mozilla, but in Edge it does stop moving but not ROTATING.
I couldn't find any help on official MS Website.
Thank you in advance for your help !

Here's my CSS:

```
/* 6. Animation cosmonaute */
#cosmonaute {
    background-image: url('Sources/img/cosmonaute.png');
    width: 81.9px;
    height: 89px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:-10%;
    -webkit-animation-name: animCosmonaute;
    animation-name: animCosmonaute;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes animCosmonaute {
    0% {bottom:0; left:0;}
    25%{bottom:15em; left:15em;}
    50%{bottom:30em; left:30em;}
    75%{bottom:45em; left:45em;}
    100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5,1.5);transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5,1.5);bottom:60em; left:55em;}
}
@keyframes animCosmonaute {
    0% {bottom:0; left:0;}
    25%{bottom:15em; left:15em;}
    50%{bottom:30em; left:30em;}
    75%{bottom:45em; left:45em;}
    100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5,1.5);transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5,1.5);bottom:60em; left:55em;}
}

#cosmonaute p {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20%;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

and here's my JS code:

```
// 2. Animation cosmonaute
    var play = 1;
    $('#cosmonaute').hover(function () {
        $('#cosmonaute').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
        if (play === 1) {
            $('#cosmonaute').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
            $('#cosmonaute').children(':first').css('display', 'block');

            play = 0;
        } else {
            $('#cosmonaute').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
            $('#cosmonaute').children(':first').css('display', 'none');
            play = 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you want to solve this via JS and not CSS?

Comment: I don't particulary want to use JS, I just want to find the solution. If there's one in CSS, please let me know.